# How to open FileURL in IONIC 4?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

```
 this.api.getapi().subscribe((response) => {
      let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var ref = window.open(fileURL, '_self', 'location=yes');
    })
```

Window.open is displaying an empty screen with a URL on the header(blob link).
It is working on browser but not on ANDROID and IOS

The response is giving pdf.

I need to open the file url(blob:http://localhost/6a9c5e03-8771-402c-..) in my app ionic 4.

Comment: Do you want to open only pdf or any kind of files?
Why you don't open in-app browser to show pdf files?

Comment: in-app browser is not opening blob URL link. I dont want to download pdf.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';

 constructor(private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }
 this.fileOpener.open('path/to/file.pdf', 'application/pdf')
 .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
 .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
```

Try using [Cordova file opener](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener).

Comment: how to create path/to/file.pdf

Comment: path/to/file.pdf is the directory of your file.